# Laplace transform of $\dfrac{\sin2t} t$

Tags: laplace-transform

So I'm taking a look at my notes and the professor wrote this:

${\scr L}(\frac {\sin2t}{t}) = \arctan \frac 2s$

But I can't see this anywhere in the tables. So, where does this come from?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the tables. Just use these two rules:

${\scr L}(\sin{at})=\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$ and ${\scr L}(\frac{f(t)}{t})=\int_{s}^\infty F(\sigma)d\sigma$ where $F(s)={\scr L}(f(t))$

Therefore;

$$F(s)=\frac{2}{s^2+4}$$

$${\scr L}(\frac{f(t)}{t})=\int_s^\infty \frac{2}{\sigma^2+4}d\sigma = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan{\frac{s}{2}} = \arctan{\frac{2}{s}}$$

See, it is very simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to get to the $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan{\frac{s}{2}}$ part. Sorry to bother you, but could you please briefly explain how we get the $\arctan{\frac{2}{s}}$?

Comment: Consider $\arctan{a/b}+\arctan{b/a}=x+y$, then $\tan{x}=a/b$ and $\tan{y}=b/a$. Now, if you draw a triangle and put $x$ and $y$, you see that $x+y=\pi/2$. Hence, $\arctan{b/a}=\pi/2-\arctan{a/b}$.

Answer (score 0):

I can only deduce it from the series:
$$
f(t) = 
\frac{\sin t}{t} = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{t^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}
$$
then
$$
\mathcal{L}\left\{f(t)\right\} = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} 
\mathcal{L}\left\{t^{2k}\right\} =
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} \frac{(2k)!}{s^{2k+1}} =
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} \left(\frac{1}{s}\right)^{2k+1} =
\arctan\frac{1}{s} 
$$
Using
$$
\mathcal{L}\left\{ f(2t) \right\} = 
\frac{1}{2} F\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)
$$
we get
$$
\frac{\sin 2t}{2t} = \frac{1}{2}\arctan \frac{2}{s}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Compute
$$\phi(x)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-st}\cos(xt)\mathrm dt
 =\Re\mathit e\left[\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-st-\mathrm ixt}\mathrm dt\right]
 =\Re\mathit e\frac1{s+\mathrm ix}=\frac{s}{s^2+x^2}.$$
Then notice that the Laplace transform you are looking for is the $x$-antiderivative of $\phi$ taken at $x=2$. To see it, consider $\Phi(x)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-st}\frac{\sin(xt)}t\mathrm dt$. Derivating under the integral gives $\Phi'(x)=\phi(x)$.

Of course $\Phi(0)=0$. The antiderivative of $\phi$ is therefore
$$\Phi(x)=\int_0^x\phi(y)\mathrm dy=\int_0^x\frac{s}{s^2+y^2}\mathrm dy=\arctan\frac xs$$
and this gives the result.